# Not able to leave a chat room

Tags: support, bug, chat

I can't understand what the issue is with leaving particular chat room. When I leave the room by clicking the "leave" link then after some time I am automatically joined in that particular chat room.

Can anyone please tell me if this is a site issue or what? Why does this happen? Why am I not getting to leave that chat room?

For example I am currently joining two rooms and from one room I leave the other room (see the image below):

[image: animation of leaving chat room]

After 2 or 3 minutes it comes up again and when I see the last chat message it means I joined again. Some of my Stack Overflow friends ask me "why you are coming in and leaving continuously?"

Comment: Can you clarify the "joined automatically" part please? How do you know you've re-joined the room?

Comment: @balpha check my update Question .

Comment: Hmm. Just an update: We're looking at this, but currently I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: thank you @balpha for looking for this even though after leaving all i close all window and after open the browser there one room i m already joined display.

Comment: @balpha still having an issue with leaving room i am using fire Fox browser please solve this.

Comment: Doesn't the "normal" way to leave the room work either? I.e. switching over to the room (by clicking the room name) and clicking "leave" there in the top right?

Comment: if i leav Normal way (leave)(all) then this is same issue after 2_3 mint i again show into the room :(

Comment: Is it possible that you have the chat open somewhere else, e.g. in another browser, on your phone, or something like that?

Comment: Nope it's Only in fireFox browser and also this is single tab of chat room

Comment: Happens all the time for me, no matter which method I use to leave, and without any other browser or device open.

Comment: This issue is still there. Please solve it if possible.

Comment: It was an absolute blast in the Android era [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38228740#38228740) as I continuously flew over the sidebar... Apparently this bug still exists and I cannot leave that chatroom no matter what.

Comment: I even tried to log out (all websites; all devices) and the issue still persists. 4 years after discovery. Strangely enough it will settle down after a while and I can actually leave the room.

Comment: This seems to be an issue related to some proxy stuff, I guess. This only happens when I am working. During college weeks everything is fine, and a few days after I start working, I am caught in the rooms. Then when I am away from work for a few weeks again, I am thrown out of all rooms and everything works as expected. So I would assume there is something here in the network that keeps the connection opened. Any chance you can close it from your side in such a case?